# Can i use webassembly to capture screen shot of web page?

Tags: webassembly

I want to use webassembly to capture screen shot of web page. Is that possible with webassembly?

Answer (score 2):

WebAssembly currently enables nothing that can't also be done in Javascript. In fact currently the only way for WebAssembly to interact with anything is to call into JavaScript. So, you just use the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) from JavaScript and pass the result into WebAssembly if you want to use screenshots in WebAssembly. If all you want is the screenshot itself though there is no reason to involve WebAssembly.